# VMWare share SAN volume across datastores. Is it possible?

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I have recently inherited a VMWare setup with 2 ESXi hosts and an HP StoreVirtual SAN for storage.

On the SAN, there's a 2 TB volume which has been used to extend one of the datastores on VMWare however only 25% of this volume has been used for this. The remaining 75% is empty.

I now wanted to extend other datastores using the space on this volume but it will not show up as an available volume when trying to increase datastore size.

Basically my question is whether it's possible to share a SAN volume between datastores. I thought of reducing the SAN volume size but I feel it's too risky.

Before I start thinking of moving stuff etc. I wanted to know what I'm trying to do is possible.

I will also say that the reason for increasing the datastore size is for backup purposes. During backups the datastore must be big enough to accomodate snapshots etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really, when you assign space to a datastore, it's owned by the datastore. So you have to reduce space on Datastore 1 to allocate it to Datastore 2

Comment: I see.. thanks for the reply. I feared this. Problem is I've read that datastore size cannot be reduced. I failed to mention that the datastore in question is only using 25% of the space on the SAN volume. I was hoping the rest of the space could be assigned to other datastores. 
I am now left with the option of reducing the size of the volume on the SAN but this is not recommended as results are not predictable and I might have data loss. I can't create more volumes on the SAN for moving/migrations as there's no space left. Any suggestions?